# How can i omit " which , that , who and passive voice " in sentences ?

Tags: grammaticality

This is an example that I thought "which and are" should have been omitted ; They put meat in the dishes which are filled with onion and garlic 
Was it true?

Comment: In this example, yes you can.

Comment: Yes: "filled with onion and garlic" then switches from a finite relative clause to a non-finite past-participial clause. The meaning is the same, and they are both modifiers of the noun "dishes".

Answer (score 2):

> They put meat in the dishes filled with onion and garlic

Yes, you can omit the *which are*, this is an example of a [reduced relative clause](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause) (*I think some people call it a whiz-deletion*). It occurs when the verb that follows the relative clause head(*like which, who, etc*) is a participle(either past or present participle).

Comment: @Maryprincess55321 You are welcome, is this the answer you are looking for? If so, you can accept it by clicking the "tick" button on left-hand side.

Comment: Can you raise an example for omitting relative clause heads when the verb that follows them is a present participle please?

Comment: This is an example of an omission of a relative clause head when the verb *following* (=that follows) it is a present participle.

Comment: I thought it was V-ing you mean by present participle. https://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/participlepresent.html

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean by a present participle. "following" in the example could mean "that follows" or "that's following". Did I confuse you?

Comment: Not really, but from what I have been told: “follow” is indicative present and: “following” is present participle. So both of "that follows" and "that's following" can be replaced by "following", right? If yes, can you give me an answer for  this related question please? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/472188/noun-v-ing-without-v-to-be-or-relative-pronoun